# Convert byte[] to string to byte[]

Tags: java

Let us assume that I have a byte[], I want to convert it to String and then back to byte[].

```
byte[] b = {-23, -38, 62, 22, -25, -23, 46, 106, -38, 13, -2, -46, 6, -110, 25, -82};   
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new String(b).getBytes()));
```

I receive other byte[]:

> [-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 62, 22, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 46, 106, -17, -65, -67, 13, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 6, -17, -65, -67, 25, -17, -65, -67]

Why is this happening? I can get an initial byte[] thus?

Comment: Most of the byte sequences in the _other byte[]_ are replacement sequences for invalid input. Specifically, the UTF8 replacement sequence.

Comment: Use utf16be to roundtrip your string nicely ([demo](http://ideone.com/8K7Gvp)).

Comment: The simple answer is don't. `String` is not a container for binary data.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, many thanks for your decision!